# How to create typed dataset which can have optional attributes in Spark 2.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have a need to use Datasets in Spark which can hold entities with some known attributes but also list of unknown at compile-time attributes as well. I need a simple way to pass those optional attributes through the computation pipeline and not to bother with them.

Made up code example:

```
> loaded.show
root
 |-- key: long (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- opt1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- opt2: long (nullable = true)
```

Let's imagine only key and value I know and care about at compile-time.

```
case class BusinessEntity(key: Long, value: String) {
  def businessLogic = this
}
```

If I convert dataframe to typed data set extra attributes are obviously lost.

```
loaded.as[BusinessEntity].map(_.businessLogic).toDF.printSchema
root
 |-- key: long (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

What I need to be able to do is to have them stored somewhere in the entity so at the very end of the computation pipeline (which can contain joins etc) I was able to extract them to target storage.

I could imagine using some of the following approaches to store optional data

```
case class BusinessEntity(key: String, value: String, extra: Row)
dataset.select("key", "value", "row.*")

case class BusinessEntity(key: String, value: String, extra: Map[String, AnyVal])
dataset.select($"key", $"value", 
/* Generate at runtime from attr list */ 
$"extra"("opt1").cast("long").as("opt2"), 
$"extra"("opt2").cast("long").as("opt2"))

case class BusinessEntity(key: String, value: String, extra: List[AnyVal])
dataset.select($"key", $"value", 
/* Generate at runtime from attr list */
$"extra"(0).cast("long").as("opt1"), 
$"extra"(1).cast("long").as("opt2"))
```

But neither of them wouldn't work because Spark can't generate encoders for Row/Map[?, AnyVal]/List[AnyVal]. So far I can only think of storing optional attributes as JSON-encoded string, but I can think of it as a last resort; or using Encoders.kryo to generate encoder for Map of AnyVal's. Am I missing something and there's easier way to target such problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would just define the optional values in my case class as `Option` and give them `None` as default value:

```
case class BusinessEntity(key: Long, value: String, opt1:Option[String]=None, opt2:Option[Long]=None)
```